# Can't get htmltmpl working on Windows Vista

Tags: python

I am trying to install the Python library htmltmpl as it is a dependency of the Venus feed reader.

I tried to install htmltmpl from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmltmpl/files/htmltmpl/1.22/)

When I ran the test suite I got the following output:

```
C:\htmltmpl-1.22>python test.py
This is not UNIX.
Converting newline separators in .tmpl and .res files.
1 ... cached ... FAILED
2 ... compiled ... FAILED
3 ... complex ... FAILED
4 ... else ... FAILED
5 ... escape ... FAILED
6 ... globalvars ... FAILED
7 ... if ... FAILED
8 ... include ... FAILED
9 ... loop ... FAILED
10 ... maxinclude ... FAILED
11 ... multipart ... FAILED
12 ... nestcond ... FAILED
13 ... nestloop ... FAILED
14 ... params ... FAILED
15 ... simple ... FAILED
16 ... unless ... FAILED
```

Any ideas on how I should proceed?

Comment: please do not link to a download link. If clicked you get and undesired automatic file download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://htmltmpl.sourceforge.net/python.html):

> The module should work on all platforms supported by Python. The
>   module is supported by its author only on the UNIX platform using
>   Python versions 2.1 or newer.